$|f(x)|\leq\dfrac{M}{1+|x|^a}\quad (a>1)\quad\text{almost everywhere}$
If $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$ and there exists a number $M>0$ such that
$$|f(x)|\leq\dfrac{M}{1+|x|^a}\quad (a>1)\quad\text{almost everywhere},$$
then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.
I was hinted to use the Dominated Convergence theorem or the Monotone Convergence Theorem but I don't know how to proceed. Could someone help me how can I apply these theorems to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

$|f(x)|\le M$ for $|x|\le 1$ and $|f(x)| \le \frac M {|x|^{a}}$ for $1 < |x|$.

The integral is monotonic, and $1/(1+|x|^a)$ is integrable, which is just a calculus fact.

The function is measurable and $\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \leq 2M\int_{0}^\infty dx/(1 + |x|^\alpha) < \infty$, thus $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For a proof of the latter, write it as an integral over $[0,1]$, dominated by $1$, and an integral over $[1,+\infty)$, dominated by $x^\alpha$ which integrates via the fundamental theorem of calculus to $1/(1 + \alpha)$.
